# I store a lua table packed with messagepack in redis, how can i hget it and unpack it with java?

Tags: java, lua, redis, msgpack

Redis lua script below:

```
local vv = cmsgpack.unpack(msgpack)
local mv = {[\"v\"]=v, [\"t\"]=t, [\"tp\"]=tp, [\"pt\"] = pt} 
table.insert(vv, mv) 
msgpack = cmsgpack.pack(vv)
```

and I hget the table with java:

```
@Message
public static class UserMessage {
  public String v;
  public long t;
  public String tp;
  public String pt;
}

String ret = redisClient.hget(uid, "m:v");
byte[] bytes = ret.getBytes();
MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Unpacker unpacker = msgpack.createUnpacker(in);
UserMessage[] dst = unpacker.read(UserMessage[].class);
```

but it is wrong, it can't be unpacked correctly, I dont know where is my fault?
This has troubled me for a long time...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are using a String object to get the results from HGET. You need a byte[]. A String object will do all kinds of nasty stuff, like interpreting the codepage, null characters, and such. Even if it works, it's a lot of overhead. So use a byte[], I guess your redis client has a way of doing that.

We use aredis for retrieving msgpack data from Redis. Here are some clues:

```
import org.aredis.cache.AsyncRedisClient;
import org.aredis.cache.AsyncRedisFactory;
import org.aredis.cache.DataHandler;
import org.aredis.cache.RedisCommand;
import org.aredis.cache.RedisCommandInfo;
import org.aredis.io.CompressibleByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.aredis.net.ServerInfo;

private class RawHandler extends Object implements DataHandler {

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(Object arg0, byte[] arg1, int arg2, int arg3, ServerInfo arg4) throws IOException {
    return arg1;
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Object arg0, Object arg1, CompressibleByteArrayOutputStream arg2, ServerInfo arg3) throws IOException {
    throw new NotActiveException("Not supported, deserialize only.");
  }

}

Future<RedisCommandInfo> futureOE = oRedis.oCliDpart.submitCommand(
    new RawHandler(),
    RedisCommand.ZRANGEBYLEX,
    "_ourkey#blabla.d",
    String.format("[%s;", cDbAndTable),
    String.format("(%s<", cDbAndTable));
  ...

  final Object[] val = (Object[]) futureOE.get().getResult();
  for (Object item : val) {
    if (item instanceof byte[]) {
    ...
```

The msgpack deserialization should be trivial from there.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: yes I konw I should use byte[] to do this, but my redis package is jedis(https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/), and the api hget returns String type, I guess the problem may be here...

Comment: Could well be. If you write the getBytes() to file, and view with a hex editor, you can make sure, and do some standalone tests. If it's the culprit, post an issue at jedis, and/or use [aredis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aredis/).

Comment: Any more questions? You might want to accept the answer, or roll your own.

Comment: @Jabari there are signatures in jedis to get the byte[] for all redis commands.